# How do I divide two cells when each contains a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to determine the rate of pay per hour from a cell containing a formula with the number of hours worked in a 24 hour period, divided by the amount of money earned in that same 24 hour period. The first two cells contain the start time and the end time worked, i.e.: 8:00am & 6:00pm, or 10 total hours. Using this formula, `=IF(M2<L2,M2+1,M2)-L2`. Then, I'm dividing the amount of money earned that day from two other cells: one for hourly pay (G2) and the other for miles driven (J2), which uses a simple formula `=SUM(G2+J2)`. If my first two cells combined = $80, and my other two cells add up to 10 hrs worked, the total amount earned should be $8 an hour, but it's not working out like that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Rolf and welcome to SuperUser. Please edit your question to include the formula, and if possible to provide a screenshot or an approximate what you have now, and what you expect to have at the end? Content of cell containing a formula can be used just like a normal value assuming the value there is what you expect to use in the new formula.

Answer (score -1):

**@Rolf** After Analyse your query I came to the conclusion that while **finding Per Hour Wage** you are facing some technical problems. So that as per my understanding I've created a Calculation Sheet which is finding **Hour Worked**, **Total Wages** & **Per Hour Wage**.

[image]

**NB:** Data Range is A311 to G312 (including Headers).

Now what you need to do,

**Format Cell A312 & B312 as HH:MM:SS AM/PM.**

**Format Cell C312 as HH:MM (No AM/PM).**

**Write Formula,**

in Cell C312,  **=(B312-A312)**.

in Cell D312, **=(C312*24)-1.**

**Please note** -1 is to subtract LUNCH HOUR (you can drop -1 if don't need so).

Now let me tell why I have used the above Formula instead of directly multiply C312 with E312 (Hourly Wage), Bcoz to get a whole number since Excel stores time values as decimal fractions of a 24 hour/day, where 1 Hrs equals 1/24th of a day **so  you must multiply the value in column D312 by 24**.

In F312 Formula is **=(E312*D312)** & in G312 to get **Per Hour Wage =(F312/D312)**.

**NB:** Change the Data Range as you need.

**Since you have not uploaded the screen shot so that I've assumed the job as you have described in Query. Also, after tested the values using Industrial Standards, I've uploaded the sheet.**

Comment: @Rolf, in case you need any further assistance do write me,, and UPLOAD Screen Shot in case you found mine is different to yours.

Comment: why do you keep addressing the OP at the beginning of the answer? it's useless. And please spend 1 min reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then learn [how to format your post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Yours are all the same and not easy to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/230282

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I used to address OP just to draw attention of the person has originally posted the Query.